# Original Values changes are not reflecting in reference types variable

Tags: c#, reference

```
object a = "1411";
object b = a;

Console.WriteLine("Before Value of a " + a);
Console.WriteLine("Before Value of b " + b);

a = "5555";

Console.WriteLine("After Value of a " + a);
Console.WriteLine("After Value of b " + b);

Console.ReadKey();
```

output:

Before Value of a 1411

Before Value of b 1411

After Value of a 5555

After Value of b 1411

After Value of b also should changed to 5555 right? since b is reference types variable.

Comment: But you're changing *what* `a` is referencing. `a` is referencing a different object now. the `b` reference remains unchanged.

Comment: I suggest you read [this article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html), it has a good explanation about value types and reference types

Comment: sorry i didnt get u. what do you mean by " a is referecing a different object now "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take this code piece by piece to see what it does:

```
a = "1411";
```

This will store a reference to an object into the variable `a`. The object is a `string`, and allocated on the heap (since it's a reference type).

So there are two pieces involved here:

- The variable `a`
- The object (string) that it refers to

Then we have this:

```
b = a;
```

This will make the variable `b` reference the same object that `a` refers to.

References internally are implemented as memory addresses, and thus if (example) the string object lives at address 1234567890, then the values of the two variables would both be that address.

Now, then you do this:

```
a = "5555";
```

This will change the contents of the `a` variable, but the `b` variable will be left unchanged.

This means that `b` still refers to the old object, at address 1234567890, whereas `a` will refer to *a different* string object.

You did not change the object itself, that both `a` and `b` were referring to, you changed `a`.

As Marc said in a comment, you can liken this to giving you the address of a house on a piece of paper. If you give a piece of paper to your friend, writing up the same address on that second piece of paper, you are referring to the same house on both.

However, if you give your friend a paper with a *different* address on it, even if the two houses looks the same, they're *not the same house*.

So there's a big difference between *reference type* and *variable containing a reference*.

Comment: int a = 10;

            object b = a;


            Console.WriteLine("Before Value of a " + a);
            Console.WriteLine("Before Value of b " + b);

            a = 20;

            Console.WriteLine("After Value of a " + a);
            Console.WriteLine("After Value of b " + b);

            Console.ReadKey();

  Output is 
  Before Value of a 10
   Before Value of b 10

  After Value of a 20
   After Value of b 10

Comment: Yes, that is correct, `a` is not a variable containing a reference type. When you store the value of `a` into `b` you're boxing the int, making it into an object on the heap. Now you have the `a` variable containing the value `10`, and the `b` variable containing a reference to a boxed *copy* of the value `10`. When you change `a`, `b` still refers to the same old boxed copy of the value `10`. You're not storing a reference to the variable `a`, you're copying its contents, which is an int, a value type.

Answer (score 3):

Let's do this with numbers:

```
int x = 1411; // now x is 1411
int y = x; // now y is 1411

x = 5555; // now x is 5555

Console.WriteLine(y);
```

Now: what is `y`? Simple: it is still `1411`. Assigning a new value to `x` doesn't change `y`. The same is true with reference-types, but simply the "value" of a reference-type variable *is the reference*. Not the object.

If you assign a reference-type variable to be a *different value* (i.e. to point at a different object), that only affects that single variable.

Now, if you did:

```
var x = new SomeClass { Foo = "1411" };
var y = x;

x.Foo = "5555";

Console.WriteLine(y.Foo);
```

Then **this** would print "5555". The difference now is that we have one object, and both reference-type variables point at the same object. We have changed a value *of the object* (not the reference), so updating that changes it no matter how you get to the same object.

Comment: object is reference type variable which references to a. so what ever changes made to a. should reflect to b right ?

Comment: @user2745829 you need to separate out two different concepts: "changes made to the value of a" (which is: the reference), versus "changes made to the object that a refers to". The latter will indeed reflect via `a` or `b`, but the former: not. As an example: I give you a piece of paper with a street address on. I give your friend the same address. If I paint the house door red, then if either of you goes to the address on the paper, you'll find it has a red door. If, however, I then give you a **different** piece of paper with a **different** address, then you are looking at *different houses*

Comment: what is difference between Int and Object. since both do same right

Comment: @user2745829 the only interesting difference is that an `int` doesn't have any mutable properties - but the rules of assignment changes work identically

Comment: int[] a = { 1, 2 }

               int[] b = a;


          Console.WriteLine("Before Value of a[0] " + a[0]);

          Console.WriteLine("Before Value of b[0] " + b[0]);


            a[0] = 10;


            Console.WriteLine("Before Value of a[0] " + a[0]);

            Console.WriteLine("Before Value of b[0] " + b[0]);


            Console.ReadKey();






Output:

Before Value of a[0]  1

Before Value of  b[0]  1

After  Value of a[0]   10

After  Value of  b[0]  10


Since Array and Object are reference type variables.

Comment: @DerrickJeevan in that example you only have one actual array; and two variables that refer to that same single array. So `a[0]` and `b[0]` are dereferencing the *same location*. `a` and `b` here are *just the references* - not the array(s). In my example, the values of `a` and `b` are the *addresses* - not the house. If both people have a copy of the *same address*, then they are going to go to the same house to check what colo[u]r the door is.

Comment: int a = 10; object b = a; Console.WriteLine("Before Value of a " + a); Console.WriteLine("Before Value of b " + b); a = 20; Console.WriteLine("After Value of a " + a); Console.WriteLine("After Value of b " + b); Console.ReadKey(); Output is Before Value of a 10 Before Value of b 10 After Value of a 20 After Value of b 10

Comment: @DerrickJeevan is there a question to go with that? what part of that is unexpected? Note in particular that the `object b = a;` line is not "assign the address of `a` to the reference `b`"; it is "take the value of `a` and make a boxed copy of that value on the heap, and assign the address of the boxed copy to `b`"

Comment: object b is referencing int a, a is changed from 1 to 10. but still object b is 1. how is it ?

Comment: @DerrickJeevan no, it is entirely incorrect to say that "object b is referencing int a". I even told you what *does* happen: the *value* of `a` is retrieved, and that value (`123` or whatever) is "boxed" into a box on the heap; the reference (basically === address) of that new box is stored in `b`. An integer such as `123` has no notion of "and I came from `a`" - it is just an integer. The boxed copy has no relationship with `a` *whatsoever*